# Filter out questions by users that match certain criteria

Tags: feature-request, new-users, filtering

Is it possible to add the ability to automatically hide users that match the criteria:

- Username matches the form **userXXYYZZ**
- 1 Question Asked
- 0 Answers
- 0 Votes
- Reputation 1

I realize this will eliminate over 50% of the android tagged questions but I find the motivation to answer such posts to be very low.

Comment: I have the same need. I follow the Meteor tag, and I find that many questions are asked by people who haven't bothered to make any effort to learn even the basics of Meteor—they haven't done any tutorials, they haven't read even the introduction on the docs, nothing. If I'm foolish and answer such a question, I get a stream of comments asking me how to implement my solution, because they don't know the basics of how to structure a Meteor app etc. Like @Error 454, I've taken to just ignoring such questions instead. I feel guilty ignoring; is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to write a userscript for that. (There's probably nothing for that on Stackapps yet.)

However, you cannot read out those user attributes easily. You need some heuristics. But a pretty simplistic one is to look for the absence of badges. One of the first badges people get is `Scholar` for `Asked a question and accepted an answer`.

```
$(".question-summary").each(function (q){
    if (! $(q).has(".badgecount")) $(q).hide();
})  // or something like that
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is more focused around the *content* than the *users*. If you don't like `android` questions, ignore that tag.

Comment: I like android questions, I just don't like answering questions that will never be marked as answered.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet had to start somewhere.

Comment: This isn't about new legitimate users, this is about people that are abusing the system by creating a new user for every question.  It's quite obvious which questions fall under this category.

Comment: I completely understand and appreciate your consternation. The "low quality question" moderator flag might be useful, too.

Comment: Not all questions of this type are of low quality.  There isn't a relevant flag for this situation.

Comment: @Error: worth noting that, in the long run, answers to *good* questions stand to benefit far more people than the user originally asking it. Don't get too hung up on that checkmark... Answer the *questions* that appeal to you.

Comment: @Error: If there really is a user making new accounts for each question, flag one of the questions for moderator attention, so that the moderator can verify the sock-puppeting and either merge or delete the duplicate accounts.